# How to make second item sticky inside ListHeaderComponent of Flatlist in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, jsx, flatlist

How can I make the second item(View />) of ListItemComponent as sticky in React native ?
If I using stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} then whole ListHeaderItem is becoming sticky ?

```
const renderHeader = () => (
  <View style={styles.header}>
    <View style={styles.item1}>
    </View>

    <View>
    </View style={styles.stickyHeader}>
  </View>
);

return () {
  <FlatList 
    data={data}
    renderItem={renderItem}
    stickHeaderIndices={[0]}
    ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
  />
}
```

Comment: This is because the whole `ListHeaderComponent` is the `0`th index of the `Flatlist`